# How to add an image using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, image

```
for (var i = 0; i < itemNumber.length; i++) {
    tableres += '< tr>';
    tableres += '<td>' + itemNumber[i] + '</td>';
    tableres += '<td>' + itemName[i] + '</td>';
    tableres += '<td>' + itemType[i] + '</td>';
    tableres += '<td>' + itemDesc[i] + '</td>';
    tableres += '<td>' + itemStock[i] + '</td>';
    tableres += '<td>' + itemPrice[i] + '</td>';
    tableres += '</tr>';
}
tableres += '< /table>';
```

In this code, in the itemType there are 5 different types. I'd like to replace this type by an image that I have saved. How do I do this?

The different types are
- Electronics, Fashion, Sporting Goods, Entertainment, Toys.

Those are also the values for the item types.

Comment: Add an image tag? Question is way to vague.

Comment: How are the image urls? What values do the types have?

Comment: Don't forget to fix (remove) those blanks in the `< tr>` and `< /table>` tags.

Comment: It's a bit unclear in the current state of the question. You have to provide more info.. for example what is this `itemNumber`

Answer (score 1):

You can add image like this:

```
tableres += '<td><img src="' + itemImage[i] + '"/></td>';
```

or

```
tableres += '<td><img src="http://.../yourimage.jpg"/></td>';
```

Based on my guess, this is what you want.

Comment: I'd opted for `'<td><img src="/path/to/' + itemImage[i] + '.png" alt="'+ itemType[i]  +'"/></td>'`, but yes ;-)